# How to fix PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, metamask

so I'm trying to launch a selenium instance that comes installed with metamask build version 9.8.4 and now I'm trying to get Selenium to click on buttons and complete the sign-in process through importing from recover seed phrase. Everything was going well until I tried to click the "Get Started" button via selectors where I come across the PermissionError. I tried running the code through my text editor & CMD both with Admin permissions however I still get the same errors.

My Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_extension('metamask-extension-9.8.4')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options = options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

time.sleep(5)

get_started_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button')
get_started_button.click()

input('Press [ENTER] to close browsers...')

driver.quit()
```

Full Error Log:

```
Python - script.py:6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Rias\Mekaverse Spoof\script.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options = chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\options.py", line 202, in to_capabilities
    chrome_options["extensions"] = self.extensions
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\options.py", line 109, in extensions
    file_ = open(ext, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Rias\\Mekaverse Spoof\\metamask-extension-9.8.4'
[Finished in 0.832s]
```

Comment: [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium%2FWebDriver%2FChrome%2FOptions:add_extension) say _The local path to the .crx file_ but you appear to have given a directory name.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the correction, i was using crx earlier but my friend told me to use the source code instead. 

I can load my instance properly however I get the error: 
"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector:An invalid or illegal selector was specified" 

which is why I originally added time.sleep(5) as I thought the site didn't fully load when the button click code was initiated. How would I go about to fix that?

Comment: XPath and CSS Selector are different languages. You passed XPath to a CSS routine. The CSS selector would be something like `# app-content div div div[3] div div div button` (not 100% sure on that one). Or you could just use an xpath find instead.

Comment: I was using xpath originally but switched to selector hoping I would have a better solution. This is the code I used for xpath.

https://pastebin.com/CtxJRwP4

The error I get is 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button"

I thought I got the wrong xpath originally however when I used 

$x("//*[@id=\"app-content\"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button")

in the selenium instance's console, it is able to locate the button via xpath successfuly.

Comment: Interesting... but I don't have a good solution. It would be worth asking a new question with the code and commentary from this last comment of yours. It more likely to attract people with xpath and selenium experience.

Comment: gotcha, thank you for the help!